# Umbraco generated links broken when switching from IIS express to local IIS

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, umbraco, umbraco7

How do you let Umbraco know the root of the project?

I developed an Umbraco site using IIS express when I deployed it to local IIS all of the relative links are broken.

I have control over all the links I generated but not over the Umbraco generated links.

I'm using Umbraco 7.4.2

For example, the root of my project used to be "//localhost:01010/" now it is "//localhost/sitename/"

The Umbraco generated links does not consider /sitename so an Umbraco generated link will look like "//localhost/media/50/img.png" instead of "//localhost/sitename/media/50/img.png"

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! Can you please elaborate your question having your effort like code or something so that people could get your problem early and help you? Thanks!

Comment: Broken how? Unless you are explicitly using absolute urls the generated urls should be relative. Please provide examples, your version of Umbraco, more details about setup e.g. are you using hostnames and how are you rendering the links.

Comment: @ProNotion I installed umbraco 7.4.2 from a nuget package. The site works fine both on local iis and iis express but all of the images are missing from the site and back office when I run the site on local iis.

Comment: Sorry for asking the obvious but do your media files actually exist in the local instance?

Answer (score 0):

Two things to check

1. get rid of the umbraco.config file as it contains the cache for the OLD site and do 'Re-publish entire site'
2. remove the contents of App_Data/ClientDependency folder.

See https://our.umbraco.org/forum/getting-started/installing-umbraco/19071-Moved-Installation-to-new-server-umbracoconfig-issue